How do I make the VLC flatpak adapt to the my system's theme?
system information
My system is Ubuntu-MATE Release 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 64-bit, the desktop environment is "MATE 1.26.0". I have both Flatpak and Flatseal installed on my system.
backstory
I had VLC snaps package installed for long enough to notice that it launches slowly. So I deleted it and installed the .deb package instead and I was surprised that VLC adopted my desktop theme (which is Yaru-MATE-dark) by default, this happened neither when I ran the snaps package nor when I was on a windows install. But the .deb package is not well updated (at the time of this writing, the debian package is on the 3.0.16 release, while both snaps and flatpak are on 3.0.20). So anyway I deleted it to install the flatpak (flatpak install org.videolan.VLC) which is as fast, well updated and actually plays some video a little better. So everything is great except that VLC is not adopting the system theme.
the problem
So I took it as an exercise to try to solve this, and I switched to a better supported theme, Yaru-dark. Now every single flatpack on my desktop (GNOME Totem videos, Amberol music player, flatseal, Gecko based web browsers, Bottles...ect) is following the system's theme except VLC. I've been autistically scraping the internet(mostly stackexchange forums, Arch Wiki and it's foss. I tried the documents for flatpak too) for solutions, I don't know why I just felled the urge to do so.
things that I tried
and I tried the following commands:
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=$HOME/.themes  
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=$HOME/.icons  
sudo flatpak override --env=GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark  
sudo flatpak override --env=ICON_THEME=Yaru-dark  

where "Yaru-dark" folders are in "~/.themes" and "~/.icons". This did the job for most of the GTK based flatpaks.
flatpak install org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru-dark

this did the job for the rest of the GTK based apps I think, it fixed appearance for both Firefox' History manager and its' right-click menu.
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2

And this did the job for Amberol, an app that is based on QT (i.e better suitable for KDE than for GNOME DE). And I thought this would have done the job for VLC but nah.
It looks like VLC is based on an older version of QT, which when installed on a Gnome/gtk based DE will read these options from a file "~/.config/Trolltech.conf" where there is a line
style=GTK+
that sets things to be compatible. The problem is that when flatpack installs VLC (org.videolan.VLC) it installs a runtime "org.kde.Platform" for it. How do I set it from this to read the trolltech.conf file?
Another thing that I tried is to install Kvantum (sudo flatpak run org.kde.KStyle.Kvantum), which didn't change anything on my system, I think it is a GUI app but it didn't appear on my menu.
TL;DR
I want to know if there is a method to make the VLC flatpak abide to the Yaru-dark theme on Ubuntu-MATE 22.04 LTS. I saw on Reddit that it worked for someone who has Arch by default without any tweaking. Why !?
